# Android Firebase Automatically Disconnects From Server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I leave the app for 1 or 2 minutes without doing anything with the server firebase automatically disconnects and it doesn't get back the connection even if the app is sent to background and came back to foreground  it only works when launching another activity and I also tried to manually force firebase to reconnect by this code

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
```

but this did not work too! do anyone know how to solve this problem?

**Update :**

I found this in the Firebase documentation

> On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce
>   bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no
>   pending write or onDisconnect operations, and is not explicitly
>   disconnected by the goOffline method, Firebase closes the connection
>   after 60 seconds of inactivity.

So I need a way to stop firebase from automatically doing this or at least when i need a connection it connects back to the server

Comment: are you writing the `goOnline()`, in onResume ?

Comment: @NiravBhavsar I am testing the goOnline() with a click listener and then checking my connection but it doesn't work

Comment: please remove from click listener and write your code, for `goOnline()` in `onResume` and check.

Comment: @NiravBhavsar Still not working

Comment: The behavior you quote should have no effect when the app is active and has active listeners. But this is very much a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) now. Instead of describing what you think is the cause of your problem, describe the actual problem and show the [minimal code that reproduces it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you fixed it? I am keeping a listener to a ref but when I am not authed the ./info/connected keeps changing to false after 1 minute